# Issue in testing using scalatest

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I just set up a new scala project with sbt in IntelliJ, and wrote the following basic class:

Person.scala:

```
package learning.functional

case class Person(
                name: String
                 )
```

Main.scala:

```
package learning.functional

import learning.functional.person

object Main{
    val p = Person("John")
}
```

PersonTest.scala:

```
import learning.functional.Person
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class PersonTest extends FunSuite {
  test("test person") {
    val p = Person("John")
    assert(p.name == "John")
  }
}
```

When I try to run sbt test, it throws the following error:

```
## Exception when compiling 1 sources to /Users/johndooley/Desktop/Scala/scala-learning/target/scala-2.13/test-classes
[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
[error]   unexpected value engine in trait FunSuite final <expandedname> private[this]
[error]      while compiling: /Users/johndooley/Desktop/Scala/scala-learning/src/test/scala/PersonTest.scala
```

What could be the reason for this? My build.sbt file:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "1.9.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "scala-learning"
  )
```

Project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

I have tried invalidating cache and restarting, doing clean, update, compile, but nothing works.

Comment: You were using a Scala 2.10 library in Scala 2.13 project. This cannot work. As you found out, better to use the `%%` notation to automatically pull the right Scala version of the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by modifying my dependency to the following:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.14"
```

and completely reloading the sbt shell